# How can I window a .mat file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, window

I have a .mat file column vector with 34069 rows (entries) and I'm trying to make windows of 5 with 1 overlap. This is my code so far and when I run it I get an error saying:

`"Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer."`

What can I do to avoid this error?

```
data = importdata('average_degree_und.mat');

Channels = 3;
samples = 34069;
window = 100;
overlap = 000;
delay = 0;      % Samples Delay between compared windows. 

max_delay= window-1
step = window - overlap;
points = floor((samples-window)/step);
matrix = zeros(Channels, Channels, points);

% Verification of step & window validity 
if step > window
    error('The step cannot be greater than the window')
end
```

Comment: Where is the recursion in your code??? Is this the whole code that you are using?

Comment: Yes that's all. Is that what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: If this is all the code that you are running, there is no recursion and you should not get any error. I have just tested this code and it returns no error

Comment: The error must be coming from the function `importdata` in the first line. The rest of the code are pretty simple assignations which do not cause an error. if it is already a '.mat' file, you could try using the function "load" instead of importdata. Something like: `data= load('average_degree_und.mat');`

Comment: @Hoki I generated a dummy column vector of the same size. There is no error caused by the `importdata`

Comment: The error message means that you have a function calling another function 500 times or more, in other words, you may have ended up in an endless loop somehow. This seems unlikely to happen anywhere here. However, just in case, I would avoid to use the variable names `step` and `window` since these are names of matlab functions. You could try it again after restarting matlab and see if it works then.